# Server Connection with public IP

Tags: server, ip, firewall

I have setup a simple HTTP java server running locally on port 8000. It simply prints a message "Hello world" when a request comes. When I try to ping it from the browser by running http://localhost:8000/test I get my message printed.

I want to get the same results from another computer that is not local. When I try to use my public IP lets say http:/43.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000/test (even from the same machine) I get an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED .

I probably suspect that has something to do with the firewall. Can anyone guide me a little more because I lack the experience?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the server in a LAN behind a DSL router, or do you have direct connection to the internet? If the former you need to configure port forwarding on your DSL router.

Comment: No it is not at a LAN. The server runs in my pc connected to the internet directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved my problem. I needed to open a forwarding port in my router that maps my local ip address to the public. My router is TP Link so this what I did:

http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-72.html

Also in order for this to work every time and not to have to reconfigure this every time I reconected to the router (because I get a new local IP), I have created a static local ip for my server following this guide:

http://www.tp-link.com/us/faq-182.html

Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what host OS your server/firewall is running so I'll keep this generic...

Without knowing your application, it seems like the server is sending a reset (RST packet) when the first SYN packet shows up indicating that the port (on that interface [your external]) is closed. You can do a quick port scan from here (https://mxtoolbox.com/PortScan.aspx) if you don't have access to a remote machine to test with. Odds are, TCP/8000 will not be open.

If it is, in fact, closed, you'll have to look at the firewall that your host OS is running and find out how to allow TCP/8000 to your host. In a major firewall vendor, your rule would look similar to this:

```
Source: Any
Destination: Your Public IP Address
Service: TCP/8000
Action: Allow
Logging: Full
```

That being said, you mentioned this was a PC so look into "iptables" (if you're running *nix) or the Windows Firewall (if you're running Windows) on adding firewall rules (Unfortunately I just joined and can't ask questions/comments, yet).

If you really want to find out what packet is being sent, run a tcpdump on your external interface (let's say eth1) (assuming your remote IP is 1.2.3.4 and your home public IP is 4.5.6.7):

> tcpdump -nn -vvv -e -s 0 -X -c 100 -i eth1 host 1.2.3.4 and host
>   4.5.6.7 and port 8000

Here you're looking for the SYN/SYN-ACK/ACK for a successful TCP negotiation or SYN/RST if there is a firewall rejecting (not dropping) the TCP stream to the port.

Once the port is open on the host OS firewall, take a look at the application to make sure it's configured properly. If this were a standard webserver, you could take a look at the configuration files for the "Allow from" directives to make sure that everyone can access the site. If this is a custom application that you've created, you'll have to check this yourself.